# org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog destroyHarder

Tags: firefox, selenium

I am getting the following INFO while executing Selenium Scripts using Java, in firefox.

```
org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog destroyHarder

INFO: Command failed to close cleanly. Destroying forcefully (v2). org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog@79b06cab

Selenium Version :2.44
Mozilla 34
```

I tried with different versions of firefox(35,36) and latest selenium versions also but still same issue.

I tried with a new workspace  but of no use.

This is just an INFO but my script execution exists after getting this info.

When I Googled, i found this was a bug in firefox v-29 but it was fixed.

Here is the code which i tried :

```
public class Test1 {  
  @Test

  public void test(){

    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    String text=driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath to check for Gmail")).getText();
    System.out.println("Text :"+text);

      }
}
```

Thanks in Adv.

Comment: Update your Selenium Jars. Selenium server + binding 2.47.1

Comment: Tried this but Not working....

Comment: Do you have update your browser too?

Comment: Yes I have update Firefox too......m not getting this issue with chrome.